# Youtube API returning Insufficient Permission when requesting comments

Tags: php, api, youtube-api, authorization

I'm trying to retrieve comment threads for a users video but I'm getting a 403 Insufficient Permission error.

My oAuth client in the developers console has the Youtube Data v3 API enabled and I set the youtube scope when the token is generated.

Here is the client I use to authorize the app in the oauth flow. I've tried both the youtube scope and the youtube.readonly scope and neither expose commenThreads.

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($auth_config['client_id']);
$client->setClientSecret($auth_config['client_secret']);
$client->setRedirectUri($auth_config['redirect_uri']));
$client->addScope(Google_Service_YouTube::YOUTUBE);
$client->setAccessType('offline');
```

Elsewhere in my app I use the token like below.

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAccessToken($access_token);
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);
$comments = $youtube->commentThreads->listCommentThreads('snippet', [ 'videoId' => $videoId]);
```

I can view the users videos and as far as I can tell I should have permission to view comments too. What am I missing? My code is almost identical to the PHP client library example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. Using the force-ssl scope fixed it.

```
$client->addScope(Google_Service_YouTube::YOUTUBE_FORCE_SSL);
```

Not sure why the ssl scope works when the plain youtube scope doesn't, especially for just listing comments.

Answer (score 1):

For JavaScript developers

```
var OAUTH2_SCOPES = [
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl'
];
```

to retrieve comments from the YouTube API add
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl
this into OAUTH2_SCOPES array